# Async callback for EventEmitter

Tags: javascript, typescript, asynchronous, callback, promise

Is it possible to do provide an async callback to an EventEmitter in TypeScript or JavaScript?

`someEmitter.on("anEvent", async () => console.log("hello"));`

Will this cause the function to be run asynchronously? If so, why would one ever not use an async function on an EventEmitter?

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to do provide an async callback to an EventEmitter in TypeScript or JavaScript?

Yes, you can provide an async function to an eventEmitter and that will allow you to use `await` inside the callback, but it does not magically make your function run asynchronously.

It also will not change anything outside of your callback function.  The eventEmitter will call your callback when the event occurs.  Your callback will end up returning a promise that the eventEmitter object will not do anything with.

So, you can do it in order to use `await` inside your callback function (for your own internal reasons), but it doesn't change anything else outside the callback.  It doesn't change how the eventEmitter does the rest of its business in any way.

> Will this cause the function to be run asynchronously?

No.  It doesn't change how your function is called.  If your function consists entirely of synchronous code, it will still be called and run synchronously.

FYI, this is true for any function declared `async`.  That does not change how the function is called in any way.  It changes a few things that you can do inside the function and it forces the function to return a promise, but it doesn't change how the function is called.  Synchronous code is still synchronous code whether its in an async function or a regular function.  I'd really suggest you read a lot more about what an async function actually is.